# How to safely remove python2.7-dev and libpython2.7-dev from ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, python, python-2.7, software-uninstall

Since a long time ago I had stopped development with python 2.7. As python 2 has been deprecated how can I safely remove python2.7-dev and libpython2.7-dev from my system.

Can I simply do

```
 sudo apt remove python2.7-dev 
 sudo apt remove libpython2.7-dev
```

Is removing python2.7-dev,while keeping python2.7-minimal, will brick my system?

Comment: I would *not* recommend removing python2 on a 18.04 system; you'll find it is automatically removed as you upgrade to a 20.04 or *focal* system (unless you've manually installed the packages directly or via package caused them to be installed), at least that's my experience/2c.   *We cannot know every package you have installed on your bionic system, thus know how necessary it is for you*

Answer (score 1):

The `python2.7-dev` and `libpython2.7-dev` packages have never been *required* on any Ubuntu system -- they have always been optional add-ons for application development.

You can safely uninstall both packages.

---

Note for Future Readers: The `-dev` packages are not the same as the stock install of Python2.

- If you're running 18.04, DON'T uninstall all Python2 packages. Doing so will break your system (the Python2-to-3 migration was still in progress).
- All of Python2 can be safely removed from Ubuntu 20.04 and newer systems...unless you are running a Python2 application. (The Python2-to-3 migration was complete).